# Setting bounty from Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bounties

I can easily set "**bounty**" from any Stack Exchange site as there is a option under every question. But in the android app, there is no option to add bounty! Is this feature missing? Or my eyes missed the option?